# Filter table on click error: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filtering

I am new to React. What I wish to complete here is to allow user to filter reward result onClick. While the rewards have different status, so I pass the key status to update filteredReward state. However, in RewardTable component where the table should be rerender according to status of reward, pending, confirmed etc. I got this error

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at new RewardRow (tiyugurugu.js:84:74)
```

Here is the [link to edit in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tiyugurugu/1/edit?js,console,output)

And this is the code.

```
class RewardTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var reward_rows = [];
    if(this.props.filtered !== "all") {
      this.props.rewards.filter(function(reward){
        return reward.status === this.props.filtered;
      },this)
      .map(reward => {
         reward_rows.push(<RewardRow key={reward.promotion} reward={reward}/>)
      });
    } else {
      this.props.rewards.map(reward => {
         reward_rows.push(<RewardRow key={reward.promotion} reward={reward}/>)
      });
    }


    return(
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Promotion</th>
            <th>Reward</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {reward_rows}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

class RewardRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <tr>
        <td>{this.props.reward.promotion}</td>
        <td>{this.props.reward.reward}</td>
        <td>{this.props.reward.status}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

class RewardFilter extends React.Component {

  render() {
    var filters = [],
        status = [
          "all",
          "pending",
          "confirmed",
          "rejected"
        ];
    status.map((status) => {
      filters.push(<span onClick={this.props.onFilterChange.bind(this, status)} key={status} className="btn btn-default">{status}</span>);
    });
    return(
      <div>
        {filters}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class UserReward extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       rewards: [],
       filteredReward: ""
     };
  }
  updateRewardFilter(key) {
    this.setState({
      filteredReward: key
    });
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.rewards = [
      {
        promotion: "Ebay",
        reward: "10",
        status: "pending"
      },
      {
        promotion: "Vodafone",
        reward: "180",
        status: "pending"
      },
      {
        promotion: "PayPal",
        reward: "20",
        status: "pending"
      },
      {
        promotion: "O2",
        reward: "60",
        status: "confirmed"
      },
      {
        promotion: "myBet",
        reward: "5",
        status: "confirmed"
      },
      {
        promotion: "Rewee",
        reward: "5",
        status: "rejected"
      },
      {
        promotion: "Zalando",
        reward: "15",
        status: "rejected"
      }
    ];

    this.setState({
      rewards: this.rewards,
      filteredReward: "all"
    });
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <RewardFilter onFilterChange={this.updateRewardFilter.bind(this)} />
        <RewardTable filtered={this.state.filteredReward} rewards={this.state.rewards} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <UserReward />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

and the mock

[image]

Comment: Switch from `ES6/Babel` to `JSX (React)`

Comment: thank you! do you know why does it effect the re-render of component?